# Overriding combo box for filtering items into the combobox, how to use this.filter item

Tags: javascript, filter, combobox, sapui5

I am using UI5 framework v1.38.39 and I want to do a custom combobox (no `sap.m.Combobox` but `custom.comboboxsearch` (which include `sap.m.combobox` and `sap.m.comboboxbase`)) where I can search what is inside (searching by contain) from key and text so I have something like follow in the custom control:

```js
sap.ui.define([
        "sap/m/ComboBox",
        "sap/m/ComboBoxBase"
    ],
    function (oComboBox, oComboBoxBase) {
        "use strict";
        /*some stuff*/
        sValue = oEvent.target.value;
        aVisibleItems1 = this.filterItems({
          property: "text",
          value: sValue 
        });
        aVisibleItems2 = this.filterItems({
          property: "key",
          value: sValue 
        });
        /*some stuff*/
```

My problem is that I don't have 2 filter, the second simply replace the first one then I don't have the items from the property text only from key, I would like to have both then I tried :

```js
sValue = oEvent.target.value;
aVisibleItems1 = this.filterItems({
  property: ["text","key"],
  value: sValue 
});
```

which give me the error :

> Uncaught TypeError: p.charAt is not a function
>       at f.d.filterItems (ComboBox.js:6)

`ComBox.js` is a core file of UI5, then I tried :

```js
sValue = oEvent.target.value;
aVisibleItems1 = this.filterItems({
  property: "key" || "text",
  value: sValue 
});
```

Which also didn't work because take in consideration only `key` and no `text`, does someone has a solution ?

PS: As I use dynamic binding I suppose I cannot include items in view they are bind via another controller.

the view is :

```xml
<!--some stuff-->
<Label text="{i18n>MyText}" />
<Custom:ComboBoxSearch id="mycustombox" selectionChange='onChange'>
    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}" />
</Custom:ComboBoxSearch>
<!--some stuff-->
```

items are added from the controller

Answer (score 0):

mhm,  i dont know if i understand your question right but i think it is this what you want.

```
    <ComboBox
                    id="combobox1"
                    showSecondaryValues= "true"
                    items="{
                        path: '/yourdata',
                        sorter: { path: 'text' }
                    }">
                    <core:ListItem key="{key}" text="{text}" additionalText = "{key}"/>
                </ComboBox>
```

and in your controller it should look like this:

```
        this.getView().byId("combobox1").setFilterFunction(function(sTerm, oItem) {
            return oItem.getText().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i")) || oItem.getKey().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i"));
        });
```

so you can search for the key or the text it does not matter

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot include item in the view (or at least I think so because the use dynamical binding) that's why I override the <combobox> in a <custom:comboboxkeysearch> and try to override the basic Filter function but this is where begin my issue :(

Comment: @SylwekFr maybe you can show your whole Code? Where you initialize the combobox

Comment: first of all what is a <Custom:ComboBoxSearch ? i didnt find anything.. and second:you dont need to include the item in the view.. you can bind the items in your controller later.

Comment: it's the customize control based on comobox because in version 1.38.39 the function for filter via contain didn't exist yet so I have to create it and then create a custom control based on combobox :)
Yes that what I tell that items are binded later on :)

Answer (score 0):

sap.ui.ComboBox has a property called filterSecondaryValues which filters both the text and additionalText.
If you set 'additionalText' of the ListItem aggregation to the value of key (let showSecondaryValiues false if you dont wanna show them) and it should work?

```
<ComboBox
        showSecondaryValues= "false"
        filterSecondaryValues="true"
        items="{
          path: '/CountriesCollection'
        }">
        <core:ListItem key="{key}" text="{text}" additionalText="{key}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: It should work in version >= 1.46 as filterSecondaryValues was added at version 1.46. but I need compatibility with version 1.38.39

Comment: Ah sorry haven't payed attention to the version used. If you create a basic example using [this](https://jsfiddle.net/inui_io/pqn1cv63/) boilerplate I'll look into it.

Comment: Can I add my xml to the boilerplate ?

Comment: Yes feel free to modify it as needed

Comment: Sorry I dind't update in fiddle but I find a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268503/sapui5-custom-filtering-contains-for-a-dynamic-binding-from-controller